# How to use Font Awesome in android Holder class which does not have a context?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, font-awesome

I am trying to use font awesome in my app. But i dont know how to use it without passing context as a parameter. This is my xml file:

```
    <Button
        android:layout_below="@id/author"
        android:id="@+id/compare_btn"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/cart_btn"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/fa_random" />
```

and this is my Holder class which ofcourse does not extend activity nor fragment.

```
    public class ListRowViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        protected NetworkImageView productImageURL;
        protected TextView review;
        protected TextView productName;
        protected RelativeLayout recLayout;
        protected TextView categoryId;
        protected TextView price;
        protected Button wishListBtn, cartBtn, compareBtn;

        public ListRowViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            this.productImageURL = (NetworkImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            this.productName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            this.review = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.url);
            this.recLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.recLayout);
            this.categoryId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.subreddit);
            this.price = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.author);
            this.wishListBtn=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.wishlist_btn);
  this.cartBtn=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.cart_btn);//set Font Awesome here
            this.compareBtn=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.customer_button);//
            view.setClickable(false);
        }

    }
```

and this is a method in my recycler adapter that set's the text of textview based on json data

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ListRowViewHolder listRowViewHolder, int position) {

        ListItems listItems = listItemsList.get(position);
        listRowViewHolder.itemView.setSelected(focusedItem == position);
        String local ="http://carrottech.com/lcart/media/catalog/product/"+listItems.getProductImageURL().trim();
        System.out.print(local+"sdaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
        listRowViewHolder.getLayoutPosition();
        mImageLoader = MySingleton.getInstance(mContext).getImageLoader();
        listRowViewHolder.productImageURL.setImageUrl(local, mImageLoader);
        listRowViewHolder.productImageURL.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.reddit_placeholder);

        listRowViewHolder.productName.setText(Html.fromHtml(listItems.getProductName()));
        listRowViewHolder.categoryId.setText(Html.fromHtml(String.valueOf(listItems.getCategoryId())));
        listRowViewHolder.price.setText(Html.fromHtml(String.valueOf(listItems.getProductPrice())));
        listRowViewHolder.review.setText(Html.fromHtml("Write Review"));
        listRowViewHolder.wishListBtn.setText(Html.fromHtml("&#f001;"));
    }
```

I have been setting Font awesome using a typeface class like this:

```
public class FontManager {

    public static final String ROOT = "fonts/",
            FONTAWESOME = "fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf";

    public static Typeface getTypeface(Context context, String font) {
        return Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), font);
    }

}
```

and in my activity or fragment i used to

```
  Typeface iconCalendar = FontManager.getTypeface(getContext(), FontManager.FONTAWESOME);
  jcustomerDobIcon.setTypeface(iconCalendar);
```

but how to do it if dont have a context to pass to the FontManager class?
Please help!

Answer (score 4):

> how to do it if dont have a context to pass to the FontManager class

Get `Context` from View's which is in  `ListRowViewHolder` class using `View.getContext()` method.

Like in `onBindViewHolder` method pass Context to  `FontManager` class as:

```
Typeface iconCalendar = FontManager.getTypeface(
                         listRowViewHolder.wishListBtn.getContext(),
                                     FontManager.FONTAWESOME); 
listRowViewHolder.wishListBtn.setTypeface(iconCalendar);
listRowViewHolder.wishListBtn.setText(Html.fromHtml("&#f001;"));
```

Comment: LOL i figured that out now.. this was a stupid question to ask.. sorry i am new to android

Comment: @ShahidSarwar: Good if you identify it yourself.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Typeface m_font = FontManager.getTypeface(
                     listRowViewHolder.productName.getContext(),
                                 FontManager.FONTAWESOME); 
listRowViewHolder.wishListBtn.setTypeface(m_font);
```

you can set for as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

I had a context in the constructor which i didnt see so this is how i did it. Hope it helps someone in the future

```
 public MyRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<ListItems> listItemsList) {
        this.listItemsList = listItemsList;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ListRowViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup viewGroup, int position) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
        ListRowViewHolder holder = new ListRowViewHolder(v);


        holder.recLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.d("List Size", Integer.toString(getItemCount()));

                TextView redditUrl = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.url);
                String postUrl = redditUrl.getText().toString();
                Log.d("THe URS", postUrl);
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, WebViewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("url", postUrl);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return holder;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ListRowViewHolder listRowViewHolder, int position) {
        Typeface icon = FontManager.getTypeface(mContext, FontManager.FONTAWESOME);

        ListItems listItems = listItemsList.get(position);
        listRowViewHolder.itemView.setSelected(focusedItem == position);
        String local ="http://carrottech.com/lcart/media/catalog/product/"+listItems.getProductImageURL().trim();
        System.out.print(local+"sdaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
        listRowViewHolder.getLayoutPosition();
        mImageLoader = MySingleton.getInstance(mContext).getImageLoader();
        listRowViewHolder.productImageURL.setImageUrl(local, mImageLoader);
        listRowViewHolder.productImageURL.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.reddit_placeholder);

        listRowViewHolder.productName.setText(Html.fromHtml(listItems.getProductName()));
        listRowViewHolder.categoryId.setText(Html.fromHtml(String.valueOf(listItems.getCategoryId())));
        listRowViewHolder.price.setText(Html.fromHtml(String.valueOf(listItems.getProductPrice())));
        listRowViewHolder.review.setText(Html.fromHtml("Write Review"));
        listRowViewHolder.wishListBtn.setTypeface(icon);
        listRowViewHolder.cartBtn.setTypeface(icon);
        listRowViewHolder.compareBtn.setTypeface(icon);
    }
```